# Editing a widgets "width" in-between a specific <td> in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've been tasked with editing a mortgage calculator widget in wordpress in order to make the widget appear a bit larger.

I'm trying to edit `#MLCalcFormLoanForm table tbody tr td` one of the specific  tags has a tag width of "15" `<td width="15">`

I'm doing this in order to center the widgets data fields now that I've made the body of the widget appear a bit wider.

This site was made in Wordpress and so I have no access to HTML and no way to edit the width of that td directly. Below I've added the URL in question.

https://randcapllc.com/mortgage-calculator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So i figured this out. I simply went into the widgets forms.inc.php file which I located using a filepath i found in the inspector. I then did a search within the php file for the text string width="15" and found only 3 entries.

I changed the width value and overwrote the file.